# Karma error - Expected undefined to be defined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, karma-runner, karma-jasmine, spyon

I want to unit test my controller. I started with basic test assertions of expect API. But I am facing challenge in mocking scope methods inside a conditional check. I am getting an `undefined` error since it is not available under scope, only the global `logout()` method is available.

I tried mocking the `localStorageService` using `spyOn` as true to satisfy the condition, but that's still of no help. Any solution will be of great help to get me kickstarted.

**Controller:**

```
angular.module('app').controller('sampleCtrl',

        function($scope, $state, $http, $rootScope, localStorageService) {

            if (!(localStorageService.get('isAuthenticated'))) {

                 $state.go('home');

            }
            if (localStorageService.get('isAuthenticated') === true) {

                 //http post calls made here to perform certain operation on page load

                 $scope.someMethod = function(){

                     //do something

                  }

            }

            $scope.logOut = function() {

               localStorageService.set('property', '');

               localStorageService.set('isAuthenticated', false);

               $state.go('home');

          };
 });
```

**Karma:**

```
'use strict';

describe('Controller: sampleCtrl', function() {

    /** to load the controller's module */
    beforeEach(module('app'));

    var sampleCtrl,scope,httpBackend,deferred,rootScope;

    beforeEach(inject(function ($controller,_$rootScope_,$httpBackend,$q) {

        var store = {};
        scope= _$rootScope_.$new(); // creates a new child scope of $rootScope for each test case
        rootScope           = _$rootScope_;
        localStorageService = _localStorageService_;
        httpBackend         = $httpBackend;

        httpBackend.whenGET(/\.html$/).respond(''); 

        spyOn(localStorageService, 'set').and.callFake(function (key,val) {
            store[key]=val;
         });

        spyOn(localStorageService, 'get').and.callFake(function(key) {
            return store[key];
         });

        sampleCtrl = $controller('sampleCtrl',{
            _$rootScope_:rootScope,
             $scope:scope,
             $httpBackend:httpBackend,
            _localStorageService_:localStorageService
            // add mocks here
        });

        localStorageService.set('isAuthenticated',true);

    }));

    /**ensures $httpBackend doesn’t have any outstanding expectations or requests after each test*/
    afterEach(function() {
        httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation(); 
        httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();     
    }); 


    it('sampleCtrl to be defined:',function(){

        httpBackend.flush(); 
        expect(sampleCtrl).toBeDefined();

    });

    // failing test case - scope.someMethod not available in scope
    it('is to ensure only authenticated user can access the state methods',function(){
            localStorageService.get('isAuthenticated');
            httpBackend.flush();
            expect(scope.someMethod).toBeDefined(); 
    });


});
```

Comment: why don't you just define _someMethod_ outside of _if_, and just pass the parameters needed for it to work?

Comment: @min che : correct me if i'm wrong.. my intention is to execute that method only for the authenticated users.. if i move it out of the condition for the sake of testing..isn't it defying it? Also...i m trying to understand why it is not working and how to make it work..instead of going for a workaround for it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to get it work.
The problem was that localStorageService did not have *isAuthenticated* set to true on starting the controller. Place setting it to *true* before calling the controller.

Comment: thanks much..i didnt even think on those lines.. :-)

Comment: it resolved that issue..but it opens up new one.. since i place it in **beforeEach()** block before starting the controller.. it is triggering all the http service calls in the controller even for the test cases in which i just want to assert whether a scope method is defined or not.

Comment: i have modified the controller to show where http calls are made.. due to this... all the unit test cases where i am trying to assert a particular functionality is getting affected forcing me to resolve/mock http calls in each test case